# My "break" command is broken

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am not a programmer and I am hoping you can help me.  I am using Windows 7.

I have a .BAT file which was running fine up until yesterday, specifically what if failing is the "break" command I use to clear the contents of a series of txt files.  Now when I run the command I receive an "Access denied" error statement.

Here is the command that is giving me the error message:

> set Date1=10-26-14
>
> break > e:\folder1\folder2\%Date1%\file1.txt

And here is what appear within the command window when I try running the .BAT file

```
 E:\folder1\folder2>break  \file1.txt  1>e:\folder1\folder2\10-26-14
```

Access is denied

Oddly the command works fine in another .BAT files I have.  Below is the "break" command from that .BAT file and the corresponding text that appears in the command window - Note how the command window text that appears within this command window differs from the above command window text that accompanies the error statement

```
set Date1=10-26-14   
break > e:\folder1\folder2\%Date1%\file2.txt
```

Text shown within the command window

```
E:\folder1\folder2>break   1>e:\folder1\folder2\10-26-14\file2.txt
```

Any thoughts I what I can do to correct the problem?

Answer (score 2):

#### My “break” command is broken

You need to find an alternative solution. `break` has no effect on Windows.

> break /?
>
> Sets or Clears Extended CTRL+C checking on DOS system
>
> This is present for Compatibility with DOS systems. It has no effect
>   under Windows.
>
> If Command Extensions are enabled, and running on the Windows
>   platform, then the BREAK command will enter a hard coded breakpoint if
>   being debugged by a debugger.

To create an empty file:

1. Delete the existing file using [del](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html).
2. Create an empty file. Several ways to do this can be found in [How to create empty text file from a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/how-to-create-empty-text-file-from-a-batch-file).

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [del](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) - Delete one or more files.

Answer (score 1):

If i have to bet, the problem are spaces at the end of the variable value. Change to

```
set "Date1=10-26-14"
break > "e:\folder1\folder2\%Date1%\file1.txt"
```

While this should work without problems, it is more clear to use

```
type nul > "e:\folder1\folder2\%Date1%\file1.txt"
```

With the same 0 bytes file generated, but now it is more clear what the code is doing